# Create class Complex number in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to create class Complex number in C# with two different constructor, the first constructor takes real part and imaginary part, the second constructor takes module and argument.

```
public class Complex
{
    public Complex() { }

    private Complex(double _re, double _im)
    {
        re = _re;
        im = _im;
    }

    public static double Complex_FromCartesian(double _re, double _im)
    {
        return new Complex(_re, _im);
    }

    public static double Complex_FromPolar(double _mod, double _arg)
    {
        var _re = _mod * Math.Cos(_arg);
        var _im = _mod * Math.Sin(_arg);
        return new Complex(_re, _im);
    }

    public static Complex operator +(Complex num1, Complex num2)
    {
        return new Complex(num1.re + num2.re, num2.im + num2.im);
    }

    public static Complex operator -(Complex num1, Complex num2)
    {
        return new Complex(num1.re - num2.re, num2.im - num2.im);
    }

    public double Re { get; set; }
    public double Im { get; set; }

    private double re, im;
}
```

}

but I got the same error in both constructors
[image]
How to fix that?

Comment: Change the return type of these static functions to `Complex`?

Comment: the method Complex_FromCarhesion returns double in the header but you want to return a Complex (return new Complex). Change in the header to return a Complex.

Comment: Either return `Complex` or override implicit cast in `Complex`.

Comment: A side note: Why are you using static methods instead of real contructors?

Comment: @Treb Because those static methods would have the same signature if they were converted to constructors. `TimeSpan` struct is good example of this. I really don't understand why `Complex` is not struct here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method returns a `double` but you're trying to return a `Complex` type

Change:

```
public static double Complex_FromCartesian(double _re, double _im)
{
    return new Complex(_re, _im);
}
```

To:

```
public static Complex Complex_FromCartesian(double _re, double _im)
{
    return new Complex(_re, _im);
}
```

Comment: But how to use this constructor?

Comment: It's not a constructor. This is a static method that instanciates your class type. Call is like `Complex c = Complex.Complex_FromCartiesian(x, y);`...

Answer (score 6):

Change the return type of that method to `Complex`.

Answer (score 5):

You cant return `Complex` when double is expected.

```
public static Complex Complex_FromCartesian(double _re, double _im)
{
   return new Complex(_re, _im);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is fine.  The problem is that you've specified a return type of double and you're returning a class of type "Complex".

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the data types mismatch. It is expecting "complex" datatype and you are telling it is double. Change **double** to **complex**